# vscode change list shortcut key color

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been tweaking vscode theme to my liking. But I am unable to figure out how to change the list and the shortcut key color as shown in the pic.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like you to check the code as per the following or share your code so that the community can help.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference

Comment: I added all the properties for list and trees here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_lists-and-trees  but none are able to change the color of the shortcut keys

Comment: I found it it's pickerGroup.foreground

Comment: Perfect. Happy Coding.